# Image uploading parallely on S3 server

Tags: android

I am using TransferUtility for uploading image on Amazon S3 server. I am trying to upload 3 images one by one but it is uploading parallely. I want to upload the images one by one. How should I do it? I am using this below code for uploading:

```
private void uploadToAWS(TransferUtility transferUtility,final ArrayList<File> imageFileArrayList){

    final ArrayList<String> uploadedFileArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> failedFileArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < imageFileArrayList.size(); i++) {

        final File file = imageFileArrayList.get(i);
        final TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                Constants.S3_BUCKET_NAME,                /* The bucket to upload to */
                "Test_Images" + file.getAbsolutePath(),  /* The key for the uploaded object */
                file                                     /* The file where the data to upload exists */
        );
        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                    System.out.println("Id:- " + id);
                    if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                        uploadedFileArrayList.add(observer.getAbsoluteFilePath());
                    } else if (state == TransferState.FAILED) {
                        failedFileArrayList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                    int percent = (int) ((bytesCurrent * 100) / bytesTotal);
                    System.out.println("percent:- " + percent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Id:- " + id + " in exception");
                }
            });

    }

}
```

This function I am calling in Asynctask.

```
@Override                           
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

AmazonS3 amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(getAWSCredentials());

TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(amazonS3, context);

uploadToAWS(transferUtility, imageFileArrayList);

return null;

}
```

Please help.

Comment: Post the code where you are creating `AsyncTask`. You are probably creating 3 `AsyncTask`s and executing all of them at the same time.

Comment: I am calling it only once from MainActivity.                                                     new UploadImageInBackground(mContext,fileArrayList).execute();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so here is the issue: You are calling `transferUtility.upload()` from a loop in `uploadToAWS()`. Now you call for the first file upload but without waiting for completion (since you've put it in a loop) you iterate through the loop and call for the next file to upload, so on and so forth...

Now to avoid this, all you need to do is wait for the `TransferState.COMPLETED` event callback and once you have it, you should call the next file upload (via another call to `transferUtility.upload()`).

Also you might wanna add some code for retries in case the upload fails in `TransferState.FAILED` callback.

So your code becomes roughly like so:

```
private void uploadToAWS(TransferUtility transferUtility,final ArrayList<File> imageFileArrayList) {

    final File file = imageFileArrayList.get(i);
    final TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
            Constants.S3_BUCKET_NAME,                /* The bucket to upload to */
            "Test_Images" + file.getAbsolutePath(),  /* The key for the uploaded object */
            file                                     /* The file where the data to upload exists */
    );
    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                System.out.println("Id:- " + id);
                if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                    uploadedFileArrayList.add(observer.getAbsoluteFilePath());

                    failedFileArrayList.remove(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    i++;
                    uploadToAWS(transferUtility, imageFileArrayList);
                } else if (state == TransferState.FAILED) {
                    failedFileArrayList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    uploadToAWS(transferUtility, imageFileArrayList);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                int percent = (int) ((bytesCurrent * 100) / bytesTotal);
                System.out.println("percent:- " + percent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                failedFileArrayList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Id:- " + id + " in exception");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

This is very rough implementation of what your code *might* look like. You may want to change your entire flow which is of course better.

Comment: After uploading first image, again calling uploadToAWS() method in TransferState.COMPLETED condition, then observer is unable to set TransferListener. I dont know why is this happening?

Comment: I was writing observer.cleanTransferListener() at the last of that condition. I remove this line. Now this works. Thanks Abbas.